# Using malloc instead of new causes free(): invalid pointer error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc, new-operator

For some reason compiling the following code with gcc and running the binary it produces on Ubuntu gives a `free(): invalid pointer` error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ios>
#include <new>

struct arr_double_size {
   double *array;
   int size;
};

struct Record {
   int ID;
   std::string str1;
   std::string str2;
   int num;
   struct arr_double_size values;
};

struct Record_array {
   struct Record *array;
   int size;
};

void Copy_Read(void) {
   std::ifstream file{"in_file"};
   std::ofstream new_file{"out_file"};
   std::string line;
   while (std::getline(file,line)) {
      new_file << line << std::endl;
   }
   file.close();
   new_file.close();
}

int main(void) {
   Copy_Read();
   struct Record rec;
   struct arr_double_size values;
   values.size = 1;
   values.array = (double *)malloc(1 * sizeof(double));
   values.array[0] = 72.12;
   rec.ID = 2718;
   rec.str1 = "Test1";
   rec.str2 = "Test2";
   rec.num = 1;
   rec.values = values;
   struct Record_array record_list;
   record_list.size = 1;
   record_list.array = (struct Record *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Record));
   record_list.array[0] = rec;   
   return 0;
}
```

The contents of `in_file` are:

```
TEST TEST TEST
```

Strangely, commenting out the call in `main` to `Copy_Read` solves the problem, as does replacing the calls to `malloc` with calls to `new`. Running the program with gdb shows that the error occurs when attempting to assign `rec` to `record_list.array[0]`. Why does this occur? I have tried to give a minimal example here; previous, expanded versions of this code resulted in segmentation faults instead of the `free(): invalid pointer` error. I am aware that this is horrible code which should never be used in a serious program (I should be using standard library `vector` and `new`), but there seems to be something I do not understand and which is not well-documented (in resources accessible to beginners, anyway) about the difference between `malloc` and `new` which is the source of the problems with this code.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and compile your code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Read also carefully the documentation of [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

Comment: You cannot use `malloc()` to allocate memory for structs / classes that contain non primitive types (aka non POD types). Your `Record` struct contains fields of class `std::string` and their constructors won't be called properly if you use `malloc()`. As a general advice: Don't use `malloc()` / `free()` or `new` / `delete` in c++ at all. Use appropriate container types or smart pointers instead.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did compile with all of the options you mentioned and gcc was silent. I plan to learn more about the use of valgrind but have not had time to do so yet.

Comment: But what is insufficient is your understanding and knowledge of C++.  Yes, C++ is a very difficult programming language.

Comment: @flakmonkey - `malloc` for the user allocates a block of memory -- period. It knows nothing else about your code and has no interaction with any other aspect of your code and knows nothing about default construction of any other object. It just allocates a block of memory returning a pointer to the new block on success, or `NULL` otherwise. The C++ `new` counterpart, by comparison, does know about the object being constructed and will default construct a new object. That's why C++ has `new` instead of simply `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand about the difference between malloc and new

The you need to **read *much more* about C++**, e.g. some [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book, and a good [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site. Yes, C++ is a very difficult language (you'll need years of work to master it). Later, you could dive into the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (or some more recent C++ standard). You certainly need to understand *precisely* the role of [constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) and [destructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming)) (and explaining that takes many pages, much more than what you can reasonably expect in any StackOverflow answer).

You need to have the code of your [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to be executed (and that is done with [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) but not with [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)) - and later the destructors should also be executed, before releasing the memory. Destructors are called by `delete` (and in many other cases) but of course not by `free`. Read also about the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

You should, when possible, prefer to use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). Sometimes (e.g. for circular references) they are not enough.

Be afraid of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) tool is useful to hunt memory related bugs. You should also compile with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). You may also want to use static source code analyzers tools such as [clang-analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/). Using them may require a lot of expertise; there is [*no silver bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

Your `struct Record_array` is wrong: prefer to use `std::vector<Record>`. Read much more about standard C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

The constructor of your `Record` will call the constructor of `str1` and of  `str2` (that it, the constructor of `std::string`-s applied to two different locations). If you don't call that `Record` constructor, `str1` and `str2` stay in some undefined state (so you have some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as soon as you use them).

A major difference between `malloc` & `free` (for C) and `new` and `delete` (for C++) is the way constructors and destructors are involved. Of course, `malloc` & `free`  are ignoring them, but not `new` & `delete`. Failure of memory allocation (e.g. when virtual memory is exhausted) is also handled differently.

PS. In practice, **you should never use `malloc` in C++ code**, except -in rare cases only- when defining your own `operator new`. Because `malloc` does not call C++ constructors (but `new` does). Also, please understand that **C and C++ are *different* programming languages**, and `malloc` is for C, not C++. Many [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) implementations are *using* `malloc` in their implementation of the standard `::operator new` and using `free` in their `::operator delete`.

Comment: This does not explain why I am receiving the specific error I am receiving (`free(): invalid pointer`). This amounts to saying "your problem is that you are attempting to manage memory the C way when you ought to be managing memory the C++ way". It also doesn't explain why the code actually works if I simply comment out the call to `Copy_Read`. This isn't helpful.

Comment: It does explain it, but indirectly. I don't have the space and time to teach you what needs several chapters of a good C++ programming book. And yes, C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: I have read the relevant sections of Stroustrup's book. They do explain about constructors and destructors but it is unclear how the failure of `malloc` to call constructors causes problems in the code posted in this specific question.

Comment: `malloc` is never documented as calling constructors. But `new` is documented to call them.

Comment: @flakmonkey This statement `record_list.array = (struct Record *)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Record));` fails to call the constructors for the `std::string` in your `Record`. Then this statement `record_list.array[0] = rec;` calls the assigment operator on the unconstructed strings, leading to error.

Comment: @john Thank you! Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @flatmonkey: my answer is saying the same. I feel you could accept it.

Comment: The important thing is that C and C++ are *different languages*. C++ is just defined to be *somehow* compatible with C (with limitations you need to be aware of).